# Does participation here mean expropriation of author moral, i.e. unalienable, rights?

Tags: support

First, to @all-sending-me-to-FAQ,

Where do FAQ tell that:

- that contributions are downvoted on the basis of their formatting merits (mostly because the author had not finalized his discussion, editing and because he is restricted from most functionalities) ?
- that others may insisting deny to the author his right to his own writings?

I do not know how others but I see that new-comers (with interesting to me contributions in interesting topics) with which I'd like to communicate just are regularly kicked off this site and the interesting to me posts (by others) are being deleted. After some "friendly" deleting, closing, editing, twisting of their posts, the new-comers do not return to this site.

But spammers and abusers are living here here, imposing their rigid pseudo-professional mono-attitudes and views on others, without any restrictions.

This site is asylum - I continuously see the same few "contributors" downvoting  + inserting off-topic comments + distorting my posts every day without even reading them.

- Does participation in this site mean abduction of my writings? or to pass them to others?
- Does this site recognize natural or moral rights, i.e. unalienable, author rights? Or, it is communist site?
- Can I close my account and be sure that my writings expropriation be discontinued with my leaving?

I think I'd better be off observing communist experiments from outside.

---------- Update1, @MarkM,

I agree with you.

This insisting in responding to anything, except what had been asked, hijacking and distorting, massive inserting of repeating off-topic comments and answers into the author's topic, leading to closing or deleting, is the main reason of my leaving.

Do you always respond, distort, delete, downvote without reading or you always have problems in understanding what is being asked (what is the topic)?

Do you prefer inserting your off-topic phrases into comments just because they are not editable?

---------- Update2, once more, this is complete perversion of any common sense to give to other's more rights to authors's writings than to the writer himself.

> There are thousands of users that use
>   SF daily without issue

Is it an argument? There are hundreds mullions of psychs that live in asylums without issue... and thousands of prisons and psychiatric clinics whose inhabitants have too much time of dwelling in internet... So, what? Give others the right to block authors to their writings>

Comment: You continue to ignore the overarching issue, which is that this site has a specific flow and structure to it. This flow and structure works for almost everyone except you. This will not change to suit you. **The End**

Comment: To answer your question, at the bottom of every page is a link to the CC-Wiki license that all visitors are subject to (authors and readers). Your "contributions" to this site, like most sites, is a derivation of free public speech; and once you have made that speech public, it is the public's right to hear it (including as altered by others). So no you can't revoke what has been posted; you have willing submitted to it being edited by others; others have the same author rights as well; and everyone retains the right to not read an author's writings.

Comment: You have a moral right to not have the words of others passed off as yours.  That would be fraud.  But that does not occur here, the edit history clearly shows who added what.

Answer (score 10):

From the FAQ, which you seem to hate:

> Like Wikipedia, this site is collaboratively edited, and all edits are tracked. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your questions and answers being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

Perhaps you should read the last few words again. **"this may not be the site for you"**

There are *thousands* of users that use SF daily without issue, yet you've been so problematic that you've caught the attention of almost every single high-rep user on the site. This is *not* a discussion forum. This is *not* a place to collect all of your thoughts in a single post. This *is* a collaboratively edited site where the **only** focus is providing accurate and intelligible answers to our peers. Answers that are used to solve *real* problems in *production* environments. If you would like this site to be something different, or if you do not want to follow the rules - go start your own site.

Once again, from the FAQ that you continuously ignore: **"this may not be the site for you"**